# Want to redirect to external link but it keep stays at current domain

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

Currently I have an web application with web page (Redirect.aspx) with the following codes in its PageLoad function

```
Response.Redirect("https://redirectURL.com/folder1/folder2");
```

In my local debug, I'm able to reach the https://redirectURL.com/folder1/folder2 when i access the Redirect.aspx

However, when I hosted the web application (as Sample.com) in AWS EC2 server, when i access the https://Sample.com/Redirect.aspx it go redirected to https://Sample.come/folder1/folder2 instead of https://redirectURL.com/folder1/folder2.

Not sure whats triggering the change of website hence hope to get some helps.

Comment: Hey there could you please provide [mre]? You have provided the line but if we were to run it we wouldn't get the same issue. Could you please share the small amount of the code that will cause this issue? In doing so you might solve it, otherwise if you don't then we will be able to look at the exact issue area and find it quicker than with too little (or too much) code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found the reason. It wasn't due to code, it was because of IIS setting.

In ARR - Application Request Module, there is a  "Reverse rewrite host in response headers" feature and somehow it was turned on hence causing the issue. Turning off this solve my issue.